# How do I use gradle to generate go grpc code?

Tags: go, gradle, grpc

My build.gradle is able to generate protobuf code for Go. What do I need to change to make it generate grpc code for the Go code?

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.3'
  }
}

def grpcVersion = '1.11.0'

dependencies {
  compile "io.grpc:grpc-netty:${grpcVersion}"
  compile "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:${grpcVersion}"
  compile "io.grpc:grpc-stub:${grpcVersion}"
}

protobuf {
  protoc {
    artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.5.1-1"
  }
  plugins {
    grpc {
      artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpcVersion}"
    }
  }
  generateProtoTasks {
    all().each { task ->
      task.builtins {
        go { }
      }
    }
    all()*.plugins {
      grpc {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin - described here rather clearly

Comment: that is the plugin I am using. I am able to generate the grpc for Java. It is not clear how to do it for Go.

Comment: I'm looking to generate C# source code and having much the same problem. The above code (when using `csharp {}` instead of `go {}`) will generate csharp _protobuf_ code, but it will not generate the grpc service stubs.